# assembly, two functions in 1 file, getting Error: junk `(%ebp)' after expression

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, att

The assembly functions with commented c version:

```
/*
int f (int x) 
{ 
    return x+2; 
}

void map2 (int* one, int * another, int n) 
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
      *(another+i) = f(*(one+i));
}
*/

.text

.globl f
f:

/********************************** prologue *************************************/
    pushl   %ebp        
    movl    %esp, %ebp          
/********************************************************************************/

    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    addl    $2, %eax

/************************************* end **************************************/
    movl    %ebp, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
/*********************************************************************************/

.text

.globl map2
map2:
/********************************** prologue *************************************/
    pushl   %ebp        
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %ebx
    pushl   %esi
    pushl   %edi            
/********************************************************************************/

    movl    $0, %ebx
L1: cmpl    $16(%ebp), %ebx         // error
    jge     out

    movl    $12(%ebp), %esi         // error
    addl    %ebx, %esi  

    movl    $8(%ebp), %edi          // error
    addl    %ebx, %edi

/********************************** calls f *************************************/
    pushl   %eax
    pushl   %ecx
    pushl   %edx

    pushl   (%edi)
    call    f
    movl    %eax, (%esi)    /* *(another+i) = f(*(one+i));              */

    popl    %edx
    popl    %ecx
    popl    %eax
/********************************************************************************/

/************************************* end **************************************/
    popl    %edi
    popl    %esi
    popl    %ebx
    movl    %ebp, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
/********************************************************************************/
```

I'm getting

```
fmap2.s:44: Error: junk `(%ebp)' after expression
fmap2.s:47: Error: junk `(%ebp)' after expression
fmap2.s:50: Error: junk `(%ebp)' after expression
```

Why? There is something to do with having 2 prologues and endings in the same file?
The base-dislocation numbers of those error lines are correct.

Comment: I never use AT&T syntax myself, but shouldn't you remove the dollar signs from those addresses? (e.g. `cmpl 16(%ebp),%ebx`)

Comment: lol, so obvious. Thanks @Michael. Guess I'm just really hungry right now :P

Comment: `cmpl ebx, ebp + 16` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to gcc [documentation](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s3), you need to remove dollar signs in front of the numeric constants used for displacement:

> One point to bear in mind is that, when a constant is used for disp/scale, `’$’` shouldn’t be prefixed.

```
    movl    $0, %ebx
L1: cmpl    16(%ebp), %ebx
    jge     out

    movl    12(%ebp), %esi
    addl    %ebx, %esi  

    movl    8(%ebp), %edi
    addl    %ebx, %edi
```

Comment: That's because the `$` applies to the whole expression, it makes it an immediate. Contrary to popular belief, it does not apply to the next token. That means for example to calculate distance between two labels, you'd use `movl $foo-bar, %eax` and not `movl $foo-$bar, %eax`.